# DXA 1.4 Resolving entities tag for a include region

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.4

We've got a landing page with two includes and we are not able to recover the entities related to the include. I will focus in one example, for example the header include:

[image]

[image]

The generalHeader has a related component presentation

[image]
[image]

This page is refered in the Landing Template as `<dxa:region name="GeneralHeader"/>`

It's region view called Core/Region/GeneralHeader.jsp is recovered and it has a tag for rendering the entities related

```
<dxa:entities />
```

However no entity is recovered. When I explore the pageModel debugging the entities tag, I see that the page has the GeneralHeader region but without any entity, however this region has another region linked with the same name and this last one has the entities. The view is correctly initialised in our SharedInitializer class.

I don't know if we've got this error because a missconfiguration issue. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Include Pages are modeled as top-level Regions (named after the Include Page title).

The Component Presentations on the Include Page are also grouped in Regions (based on the CT metadata). These become nested Regions within the top-level Region representing the Include Page.

You can indeed use two levels of Region Views. If you don't need multiple Regions within your Include Page, you could also let the Region View for the Include Page iterate directly over the Entities within that single Region and render them using the `dxa:entity` tag (effectively flattening the second level).

Answer (score 0):

The region view name must differ from the pageName, e.g. HeaderRegion. Then in the GeneralHeader (included page), you must call to the region defined in the Component Template

```
<dxa:region name="HeaderRegion" />
```

Finally, the region view HeaderRegion will render the included entities in the CT.